# How to make a uiscrollview of a view inside a tabbarcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I can make a view with a `UIScrollView` without problemas, but I can't understand how to make a `View` with a `UIScrollView` and insert it in a `UITabBarController`.

I'm starting with iOS now...

Comment: well i have already a view controller. that view controller is loaded from the uitabbarcontroller. at the moment the view controller obvious load the view. but i can't understand how to make the uiscroll here is my code on the view controller to load the view: - (void)loadView { imageScrollProgramaticamente isp = [[imageScrollProgramaticamente alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; [self setView:isp]; [isp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; [isp release]; / }

Answer (score 1):

A `UITabBarController` doesn't deal with child views directly.  [It deals with child view controllers.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW15)  You need a view controller to be in charge of your scroll view, and you tell the tab bar controller about the view controller.

If you don't understand what view controllers are for or how to make your own view controller, you need to work through some iOS programming tutorials.

Comment: well i have already a view controller. that view controller is loaded from the uitabbarcontroller. at the moment the view controller obvious load the view. but i can't understand how to make the uiscroll

here is my code on the view controller to load the view:

- (void)loadView
{
 
    imageScrollProgramaticamente *isp = [[imageScrollProgramaticamente alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self setView:isp];
    [isp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [isp release];
    /*
    
    
}

Answer (score 0):

In you view controller you will need to add the following code to create a ScrollView

```
UIScrollView *srcv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.view = srcv;
//Add your elements to srcv
[srcv setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x,y)]; //Where x and y are your dimensions that will allow this to scroll
```